# Можно ли установить Mongo-PHP драйвер на El Capitan?

Tags: php, mongodb

MongoDB 3 поставил.
Стоит MAMP.
PHP не получается, ошибка.
Некоторые модули при установке пишут что не поддерживают эту новую версию osx.

Подскажите есть ли простой способ это сделать?

Comment: Покажите хоть какой нибудь вывод.

Comment: Tapped 502 formulae (535 files, 2,4M)
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.

Comment: Это есть? brew install libxml2
brew link libxml2 –force,  а также вот тут есть ответ http://superuser.com/questions/940874/homebrew-doesnt-install-new-apps-in-el-capitan

Comment: vagrant + virtualbox и забываем про проблемы